# SmallTalk - Printing contents of an OrderedCollection object using Transcript

Tags: smalltalk, pharo

```
|oc|
oc := OrderedCollection new. 
oc add: 2.
oc add: #(4 9).
oc Transcript show: self; cr.
```

Upon running the following code in Pharo, I am getting the message:

**MessageNotUnderstood: OrderedCollection>> Transcript**

When replacing 'self' with 'oc' I am still getting the same error. I am looking for a way to output the collection using the Transcript.

Why can't Transcript be the receiver of my code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remember the `object message: parameter` syntax: you're trying to send the `Transcript` message to the `oc` object, and then send the `show:` message to the object returned by that, with the `self` parameter.

What you really want to do is ask the `Transcript` object to `show:` your `oc` object. So, do that: send `Transcript` the `show:` message with `oc` as a parameter: `Transcript show: oc`. That will show the string representation of the collection.

If you were to *print each member of the collection* (instead of printing *the collection* itself), you should use the `do:` method to iterate over them: `oc do: [ :element | Transcript show: element ]`. Here you print *each of the collection's member* string representation.

```
oc := OrderedCollection new. 
oc add: 2.
oc add: #(4 9).
Transcript show: 'Show the collection:'; cr.
Transcript show: oc; cr.
Transcript show: 'Show each element:'; cr.
oc do: [ :element | Transcript show: element; cr ].
```

Gives this output:

```
Show the collection:
an OrderedCollection(2 #(4 9))
Show each element:
2
#(4 9)
```

Comment: "an instance of the class Class"?

Comment: @SeanDeNigris :O Shame on me. So `Transcript` is not a class?

Comment: It is an instance of ThreadSafeTranscript when you run headful and one of NonInteractiveTranscript when you run headless.

Answer (score 1):

Also:

```
oc do: [ :each | Transcript show: each; cr ]
```

Comment: Don't forget there's a difference between _printing a collection_ and _printing each element of a collection_.

Comment: Indeed, you're right. I just assumed he wanted to print the contents, otherwise you could just command+p the whole collection and you're done.

Answer (score 0):

Somewhat shorter:

```
oc do: [:each | each logCr ]
```